# Requesting Access Token from WSO2 API Manager via Token API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to understand on how to implement access token request from WSO2 API Manager. Given I have a login page with username and password input, how do I request the access token by using only these two parameters?

Because by referring to the Token API, consumer key / secret is required to be appended on the authorization header, which is not available during the login.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To get an access token you should first register an oauth application for it.  The client id, client secret are from the application. After that you can generate an access token from that application.

Follow these instructions to generate client id and client secret.

1. Login to the APIM Store. (https://localhost:9443/store)
2. Subscribe an Application for your api.
3. Go to the application and click on Generate Keys in the production tab.

Now the client id and client secret will be created for your application. You can use those keys to generate the access token.

Edit:

Generate Client Id and Client Secret from rest api.

Please follow : https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/publisher/index.html#guide

Comment: Actually how does the existing API Store sign in works? Because from the UI, user only needs to enter the username and password. That is what I want to achieve

Comment: @Bino You can use the rest api for this. The information of the user who needs to generate the token should be linked to API Manager. 

As the Application developer, you can create an application for your api and generate client credentials and store them in the app... You can deside whether you store both client id and secret based on the security considerations.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, you are talking about sign up. I would like to know the login process of the existing API Store, the sign page. It only ask for username and password. So my intention is to make my own login page, user will enter username and password then I shall get the access token in response. Please bear with my little knowledge.

Comment: @Bino: The existing login happens via jaggery apis. I'll point you to the code. https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/6.x/features/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.store.feature/src/main/resources/store/site/blocks/user/authenticate/ajax/login.jag#L11

Comment: that means no way i can replicate thaf in Angular based front end as there is no REST API for that exposed isnt it

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate an access token, you need to have an Oauth2 application. Token comes under a particular Oauth2 application. That is why you need to have a consumer key and secret of the application.

You can use password grant type as in https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Password+Grant

Comment: Actually how does the existing API Store sign in works? Because from the UI, user only needs to enter the username and password. That is what I want to achieve